# Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported (Kivy Application)

Tags: python, gtk, kivy, chromium-embedded, cefpython

I am building a Kivy application that makes use of the cefpython widget for kivy.

Upon execution of my program, whenever I add a Text Input widget into the view, my application crashes with the error : **Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported**

I'm in a fix as I can't seem to figure out how to work around all this.

cefpython version : 31.2

kivy version : 1.9.1

kivy-garden version : 0.1.4

pygame version : 1.9.1release

Comment: Without you showing code,  the best you can probably expect is an answer that repeats the error message: Don't use Gtk+2 and Gtk+3 in the same process (this includes your code and any modules you import)

Comment: CEF Python [Issue #261](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/261) seems related. Looks like one of packages depends on GTK 3 and some other on GTK 2. Are you using GTK 3 PyGObject library (gi.repository) in your app?

Comment: If Kivy uses it internally, then yes.